# Building both managed and unmanaged C++ applications with CMake?

Tags: cmake, managed-c++

I have a C++ project with mostly native code (core libraries + WIndows service) and a configuration GUI written in managed C++.  I've ported most of this project to CMake, but I'm stuck with building the managed C++ code using CMake.

The top-level targets look like:

```
# Native C++ static libraries.
add_library(sql STATIC ...)
add_library(w32 STATIC ...)
add_library(smdr STATIC ...)

# Native C++ programs depending on above libraries.
add_executable(logging-service ...)
target_link_libraries(logging-service sql w32 smdr)
# ... more native executables here...

# Managed C++ GUI application (doesn't link with any of the above).
add_executable(configuration-editor ...)
```

I can't find any relevant information in the CMake documentation, and most solutions I see in search results (e.g. [messages in the mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/044831.html)) involve tweaking the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*` variables.  However, this creates conflicts the other C++ projects.

How would you set up the build scripts to have two sets of C++ compiler flags, one for native libraries and one for managed applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading of various posts in the CMake mailing lists, it seems that the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*` variables are local to each `CMakeLists.txt` and inherited by child directories using `add_subdirectory()`.

So apparently, the recommended way to have multiple sets of compiler flags is to make sibling sub-directories that each set their own compiler flags.  I just added two folders `native` and `managed` and each sets their own compiler flags in their respective `CMakeLists.txt`.  Now, everthing builds as expected.

Comment: I just answered a similar question moments ago: stackoverflow.com/questions/10199904 - I wish I'd seen yours when you posted it, I could have saved you some time!

Comment: @Fraser: I just find it really a pain that this information seems obvious to CMake experts but is so hard to find for the casual CMake developer.  Thanks for the link though, it confirms that I'm on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something along the lines of:

```
project(my_libraries)
...
add_library(standard SHARED ${src_files})
add_library(managed SHARED ${src_files})
```

then you can do:

```
set(incomp_flags <list of incompatible flags>)
get_property(comp_flags TARGET managed PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS)
foreach(flag ${incomp_flags})
  list(REMOVE_ITEM comp_flags ${flag})
endforeach()
set_property(TARGET managed PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${comp_flags} <flag for managed build>)
```

The idea is that you need to get the flags for the build of the managed library, and then you need to remove incompatible ones and add the one you want.

Comment: I'm not attempting to build two versions of the same library.  I'm always building *both* native and managed components at the same time.  In both cases, the compiler is `cl` only it accepts different options.  Option `/clr` is used to tell the compiler to use managed C++ and this option is incompatible with the settings used in the native components (e.g. `/EHa` to enable C++ exception handling and Microsoft's SEH).  Further, some of the incompatible options are used by default in CMake (e.g. `/RTC1`).

Comment: That wasn't clear in your original question -- I would recommend editing it to make it clearer. I rewrote my answer with an approach that may work and it leaves the compiler flags intact if the user decides to alter them somehow, except for removing incompatible options.

Comment: I tried the `get_property()` and `set_property()` combo and it doesn't work.  Somehow, `get_property()` doesn't extract all the flags inherited from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`, so the filtering doesn't remove anything.

Comment: What version of CMake do you have? Try replacing `get_property()` with `get_target_property(comp_flags managed COMPILE_FLAGS)`. Some versions of CMake don't behave well with the `get_property()` route.

Comment: I'm using CMake 2.8.7.  I'm playing around with `get_property()` and `get_target_property()` and I'll get back to you when I have a clear idea of what works (or doesn't work).

Comment: Neither `get_property()` nor `get_target_property()` return any results (the value is always "NOTFOUND").  Besides, the CMake documentation says: "The COMPILE_FLAGS property sets **additional** compiler flags used to build sources within the target. It may also be used to pass additional preprocessor definitions."  I don't think this solution can replace flags set in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable.